# semantic UI dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 7]>                  <html class="ie7 no-js" lang="en">     <![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>              <html class="ie8 no-js" lang="en">     <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="not-ie no-js" lang="en">  <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<select class="ui dropdown search selection" id="search-select">
  <option value="">State</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>





    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.3.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.3.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search-select').dropdown();
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to implement the semantic ui dropdown with search, the dropdown box shows but it does not show anything when clicked. I believe this to be an issue with the JavaScript but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: first impression--you only need to instantiate it once, and wrap that in a doc ready function-- like: `$(document).ready(function(){$('#search-select').dropdown();});`

Comment: @Ted thanks for your reply, I updated my code and tried that but still not working

Comment: Your code works - here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mqvwnesc/, check the browser console for errors

Comment: I think the difference between your fiddle and his code is the inclusion of the full semantic.js and semantic.css files. I created a fiddle with just the dropdown.js file (like his sample code) and it didn't work so well. I created one with the full libraries included and it worked...[like so](http://jsfiddle.net/onxn7a0m/1/)

Comment: So to clarify: Include the full libraries: 

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.3.2/semantic.min.css` 

and 

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.3.2/semantic.min.js`

instead of just the `dropdown.js` file. I would guess there's something in the core that's missing from the individual file.

Comment: @ted thanks again for your help! the fiddle works, I have included the full semantic files but still the same result :(

Comment: @ted does it matter where I put the function ready part or where I put the link to the js?

Comment: Added answer below--I tested the code locally, and the old jquery seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Use a more current version of jQuery:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>`

2: Instantiate only once for an element

That seemed to fix it. The big deal is the old version of jQuery you have linked.