# Semantic UI Dropdown is not showing the drop down but everything else is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am using [Semantic UI Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) in my ASP.NET Web Forms application. Its working fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow2by6av/4). But in my application it is not showing the drop down when clicked on the selector div. Also, I can select the elements by searching but in that case too the drop down is not showing. When I inspected using Firefox, I found that `display: none` property is not changing for `.menu` class. When I researched on SO, I found these related questions: [Semantic-ui dropdown is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529467/semantic-ui-dropdown-is-not-working) and [semantic UI dropdown not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609356/semantic-ui-dropdown-not-working). I tried the solutions but none of them seem to work. I checked other css in my project none of them shows any conflict. Then, what is wrong with it? You can find my dropdown code in the fiddle.

Comment: A long shot but maybe your .menu class in CSS files has an `display:none !important;` property?

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic actually I am using the original css and it doesn't have `!important` in it. Also, I tried to use it but no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you'll have to initialize the JS part of semantic. 
Try calling the `.dropdown()` function in the `.onLoad()` of the window.

```
window.onload = function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use multiple menu classes !! .
Just read the doc :
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html .
I edit your fiddle, and it works now:

```
<div id="itdd" class="ui dropdown search button" style="background:maroon; color:white">
<span class="text">Click to select</span>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="1"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="2"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="3"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="1"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="1"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="1"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Currency</div>
</div>
```

Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ow2by6av/7/

Comment: I already tried that. You can see it in this fiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/ow2by6av/4/. But in the fiddle its working but not in my website's page. And the problem is not about displaying 1 item but the complete drop down.

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is from ASP.NET Layout, so to debug that, just run the app and give us the source code from the browser

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had `minchars` set greater than 1.  Clicking on the dropdown does not render the menu in that case.